# OSError [Errno 22] 'Invalid argument' when use... print() in Django views for local server 127.0.0.1. PyCharm

Tags: python, django, django-views, pycharm, oserror

Suddenly, the mistake appear in `Django` project, for start in local 127.0.0.1 in `views.py` that did`t modified for long time, and normally works now on production server.
Run from PyCharm

```
OSError at /Nb/
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Nb/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
Exception Location: C:\Users\shulya403\Shulya403_works\all_gid_2\all_gid_2\marketability\views.py, line 299, in Dict_by_Classes2
Python Executable:  C:\Users\shulya403\Shulya403_works\all_gid_2\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\shulya403\\Shulya403_works\\all_gid_2\\all_gid_2',
 'C:\\Users\\shulya403\\Shulya403_works\\all_gid_2',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2019.3.4\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Users\\shulya403\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\shulya403\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\shulya403\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\shulya403\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\shulya403\\Shulya403_works\\all_gid_2\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\shulya403\\Shulya403_works\\all_gid_2\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2019.3.4\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Wed, 24 Nov 2021 19:08:57 +0000
```

`line 299` - is the `print(var)` function. (There's another one point of this mistake appears in enother code line, and there's `print()` too)
Server and code normally worked for long time in this installation. I did't change any configuration files or environoment parameters...

What it`s may be?

Comment: Can you please share the `Dict_by_Classes2` function?

Comment: It's does't matter in the case - what is `Dict_by_Classes2`. It's working code, guranted. It is don't relation to code, but relation to console of PyCharm, i suppose or some environoment parametr that has strayed.